# Angular observables never come to completion handler

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables, rxjs-observables

Below is my code snippets. I wonder why it NEVER run into the completion handler?
What I wanted to do is, first call serviceA to get objectA with given route param['key'], and then call serviceB to get objectB. So, objectB depends on result of objectA which depends on given param['key'].

p.s. I am using Angular 7 with rxjs6

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.pipe(
      mergeMap(
        (params: Params) => {
          this.key = params.key;
          return this.serviceA.getObjectA(this.key);    // http request service to backend
        }
      ),
      mergeMap(
        (objectA: ObjectA) => {
          // do something with objectA

          return this.serviceB.getListOfObjectB();  // http request service to backend
        }
      )
    ).subscribe(
      (objectBList: ObjectB[]) => {
        for (const b of objectBList) {
          // do something with objectB
        }
        // the code execution ends here
      },
      () => {
        // error handler
      },
      () => {
        // completion handler
        // the code execution NEVER comes to here, WHY??
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume that `route` is the injected `ActivatedRoute`.

Each `ActivatedRoute` is bound to a **routed component** and when a route changes occurs, the current component being displayed is going to be **destroyed**, as well as its bound `ActivatedRoute`, so that's why you won't get a `complete` notification.

---

[Here's](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/create_router_state.ts#L76-L80) how an `ActivatedRoute` is created:

```js
function createActivatedRoute(c: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
  return new ActivatedRoute(
      new BehaviorSubject(c.url), new BehaviorSubject(c.params), new BehaviorSubject(c.queryParams),
      new BehaviorSubject(c.fragment), new BehaviorSubject(c.data), c.outlet, c.component, c);
}
```

Now, how are `ActivatedRoute`s bound to routed component?

Assuming you have a configuration that looks like this:

```js
{
  path: 'a/:id',
  component: AComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'b',
      component: BComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'c',
      component: CComponent,
    },
  ]
}
```

and an issued URL like `a/123/b`

you'd end up having a **tree** of `ActivatedRoute`s:

```
      APP
       |
       A
       |
       B
```

Whenever you schedule a navigation(e.g `router.navigateToUrl()`), it has to go through some important phases:

- **apply redirects**: checking for redirects; loading lazy-loaded modules; finding `NoMatch` errors
- **recognize**: creating the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` tree
- **preactivation**: comparing the resulted tree with the current one; this phase also *collects* `canActivate` and `canDeactivate` guards, based on the found differences
- **running guards**
- **create router state**: where `ActivatedRoute` tree is created
- **activating the routes**: this is the cherry on the cake and the place where the `ActivatedRoute` tree is leveraged

  It is also important to mention the role that `router-outlet` plays.

  Angular keeps track of the `router-outlet`s with the help of a `Map` object.

  [Here's](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/directives/router_outlet.ts#L42-L57) what happens when you have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your app:

```js
@Directive({selector: 'router-outlet', exportAs: 'outlet'})
export class RouterOutlet implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  private activated: ComponentRef<any>|null = null;
  private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute|null = null;
  private name: string;

  @Output('activate') activateEvents = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output('deactivate') deactivateEvents = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(
      private parentContexts: ChildrenOutletContexts, private location: ViewContainerRef,
      private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, @Attribute('name') name: string,
      private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.name = name || PRIMARY_OUTLET;
    parentContexts.onChildOutletCreated(this.name, this);
  }
}
```

*Note the presence of `activated`(which is a component) and `_activatedRoute`!*.

And [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router_outlet_context.ts#L33) are the relevant bits of `ChildrenOutletContexts`:

```js
export class ChildrenOutletContexts {
  // contexts for child outlets, by name.
  private contexts = new Map<string, OutletContext>();

  /** Called when a `RouterOutlet` directive is instantiated */
  onChildOutletCreated(childName: string, outlet: RouterOutlet): void {
    const context = this.getOrCreateContext(childName);
    context.outlet = outlet;
    this.contexts.set(childName, context);
  }
}
```

where `childName` is by default `'primary'`. For now, focus your attention only on the `context.outlet` part.

So, for our route configuration:

```js
{
  path: 'a/:id',
  component: AComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'b',
      component: BComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'c',
      component: CComponent,
    },
  ]
}
```

the `router-outlet` `Map` would look like this(roughly):

```js
{
  primary: { // Where `AComponent` resides [1]
    children: {
      // Here `AComponent`'s children reside [2]
      primary: { children: { } }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, let's see [how a route is activated](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/operators/activate_routes.ts#L178-L190):

```js
// This block of code will be run for [1] and [2] (in this order!)
const context = parentContexts.getOrCreateContext(future.outlet);
/* ... */

const config = parentLoadedConfig(future.snapshot);
const cmpFactoryResolver = config ? config.module.componentFactoryResolver : null;

context.attachRef = null;
context.route = future;
context.resolver = cmpFactoryResolver;
if (context.outlet) {
  context.outlet.activateWith(future, cmpFactoryResolver);
}

this.activateChildRoutes(futureNode, null, context.children);
```

[`context.outlet.activateWith(future, cmpFactoryResolver);`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/directives/router_outlet.ts#L132-L149) is what what we're looking for(where `outlet` is the `RouterOutlet` directive instance):

```js
  activateWith(activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver|null) {
    if (this.isActivated) {
      throw new Error('Cannot activate an already activated outlet');
    }
    this._activatedRoute = activatedRoute;
    const snapshot = activatedRoute._futureSnapshot;
    const component = <any>snapshot.routeConfig!.component;
    resolver = resolver || this.resolver;
    const factory = resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    const childContexts = this.parentContexts.getOrCreateContext(this.name).children;
    const injector = new OutletInjector(activatedRoute, childContexts, this.location.injector);
    this.activated = this.location.createComponent(factory, this.location.length, injector);
    // Calling `markForCheck` to make sure we will run the change detection when the
    // `RouterOutlet` is inside a `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` component.
    this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
    this.activateEvents.emit(this.activated.instance);
}
```

Note that `this.activated` holds the **routed component**(e.g `AComponent`) and `this._activatedRoute` holds the `ActivatedRoute` for this component.

Let's see now [what happens](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/operators/activate_routes.ts#L109-L126) when we're navigating to another route and this current view is destroyed:

```js
deactivateRouteAndOutlet(
    route: TreeNode<ActivatedRoute>, parentContexts: ChildrenOutletContexts): void {
  const context = parentContexts.getContext(route.value.outlet);

  if (context) {
    const children: {[outletName: string]: any} = nodeChildrenAsMap(route);
    const contexts = route.value.component ? context.children : parentContexts;

    // Deactivate children first
    forEach(children, (v: any, k: string) => this.deactivateRouteAndItsChildren(v, contexts));

    if (context.outlet) {
      // Destroy the component
      context.outlet.deactivate();
      // Destroy the contexts for all the outlets that were in the component
      context.children.onOutletDeactivated();
    }
  }
}
```

where `RouterOutlet.deactivate()` looks [like this](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/directives/router_outlet.ts#L122-L130):

```js
deactivate(): void {
  if (this.activated) {
    const c = this.component;
    this.activated.destroy(); // Destroying the current component
    this.activated = null;
    // Nulling out the activated route - so no `complete` notification
    this._activatedRoute = null;
    this.deactivateEvents.emit(c);
  }
}
```