# Unsubscribing from queryparammap - has this become necessary?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Googling around for subscription management in angular's `ActivatedRoute` comes up with the same reference to angular docs, which state that you do not have to unsubscribe from `ActivatedRoute` observables as it gets torn down by the router cleanly.

However, when viewing the docs themselves, it no longer has this section explaining this. I tried to use `finalize` to test if the observable was being completed when the component was being destroyed:

`this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.pipe(finalize(() => console.log('done')).subscribe()`

However, the console log was never being called. I was not sure if this was because the observable was just straight up being destroyed, or was just remaining open.

Has it become necessary to manage the subscription lifecycle for `ActivatedRoute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each ActivatedRoute is bound to a routed component and when a route changes occurs, the current component being displayed is going to be destroyed, as well as its bound ActivatedRoute, so that's why you won't get a complete notification.

I've elaborated a bit on it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62259184/9632621).

Comment: Fantastic explanation, just what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help!